# Haskell - Non-exhaustive patterns in function

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

The point of the following function is to take in a list and split the list into a tuple of 2 lists.  The first list will maintain even indexed items and the second will maintain odd indexed items.  "Pos" is the position currently at. (0 is being passed in on function call).  The initial tuple of lists passed in is ([],[])

```
split :: [Integer] -> ([Integer],[Integer]) -> Integer -> ([Integer], [Integer])
split [] (x,y) _ = (x,y)
split (x:xs) ((y:ys),(z:zs)) pos
    | pos `mod` 2 == 0  = doSplit xs ((y:ys) ++ [x], (z:zs)) (pos + 1)
    | otherwise         = doSplit xs ((y:ys), (z:zs) ++ [x]) (pos + 1)
```

Haskell is reporting

```
*** Exception: split.hs:(113,1)-(116,73): Non-exhaustive patterns in function split
```

I understand that it believes that I have not covered "some case" that should be covered, however I feel I have covered all cases.

If the list is empty -> return the tuple of lists that was passed in
Otherwise -> tack x onto one of the lists and recurse on xs.

From my point of view, this function is strictly decreasing until xs becomes [] in which case it stops.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens if the list isn't empty, but your tuple contains an empty list?

Comment: You can use `even pos` instead of `pos \`mod\` 2 == 0`. (I realize this doesn't fix your issue, but Zeta does)

Comment: It shouldn't matter, the function isn't recursing on the tuple.

Is [] ++ [x] not a valid statement?  In fact, this should almost always be the case as the tuple being passed in is, in fact, empty. Is there a way for me to specify that I want it to do the recursion in both cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no match when the first list is nonempty but one (or both) of the lists in the tuple argument are empty e.g.

```
split [1] ([], [])
```

however your second clause doesn't seem to require that either list in the tuple is non-empty so you could change it to:

```
split (x:xs) (ys,zs) pos
    | pos `mod` 2 == 0  = doSplit xs (ys ++ [x], zs) (pos + 1)
    | otherwise         = doSplit xs (ys, zs ++ [x]) (pos + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I suppose I didn't realize that (y:ys) infers a cons pair and not just "whatever's there"

Comment: @Aserian The `:` is actually one of the two constructors for a list, the other being `[]`.  You can and should treat it like any other constructor to be pattern matched on.

Comment: @Aserian A pattern that matches any list is `ys`. The *type* says that it's a list; you don't need to use any special notation in the variable to indicate it's a list. `y:ys` can only be "something consed onto something"; there's no way for that expression to end up equal to `[]`, no matter what values you choose for `y` and `ys`.